# (Pandas) How to get count how often the same value as before occured ? (and extract a new Column out of it)

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction

Im looking for a way to extract a new column out of my Pandas Dataframe, which shows a count of how often the current value occured the same as before (without interruption)

e.g. out of a Column like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10, 10, 23, 23, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12], columns=['RiseOrFall'])
```

the following column should be extracted:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
2
0
1
2
3
0
```

Something similar a user posted a few years ago:

```
df = df.groupby(df['RiseOrFall'].ne(df['RiseOrFall'].shift()).cumsum())['RiseOrFall'].value_counts()

Or:

df = df.groupby([df['RiseOrFall'].ne(df['RiseOrFall'].shift()).cumsum(), 'RiseOrFall']).size()

print (df)
values  values
1       10        2
2       23        2
3       9         3
4       10        4
5       12        1
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

BUT by the code above i am only getting showed the total values of how many times the value occured in a row, (not the counting up to it)
What i need should be a column with the same index as the column "RiseOrFall" and with the same amount of rows, like this:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
2
0
1
2
3
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.RiseOrFall.ne(df.RiseOrFall.shift()).cumsum()` to group every changes on the `RiseOrFall` column and then use `cumcount`:

```
df.assign(Count=df.groupby(df.RiseOrFall.ne(df.RiseOrFall.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount())
```

---

```
    RiseOrFall  Count
0           10      0
1           10      1
2           23      0
3           23      1
4            9      0
5            9      1
6            9      2
7           10      0
8           10      1
9           10      2
10          10      3
11          12      0
```

Note: Please assign this back : `df=df.assign(....)`